# How do I read the arguments in "args" passed to a builtin function in Python [source]?

Tags: python, python-2.6, cpython

Example (builtinmodule.c):

```
static PyObject *
builtin___import__(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    ...
}
```

How do I go about getting the arguments, `args`, in string format? I believe it would be similar to finding  the name of a function (if a callable PyObject was a function: `PyString_AsString(PyObject_GetAttrString(func, "__name__"))`), but I don't know what attributes to look for in the `args`.

Comment: Have a look at the very first page of the [documentation on C extension for Python](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is just [get the repr](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_Repr) of the object, since it's a tuple.